Slow Message Processing with AWS SQS Integration in NestJS
I'm currently working on integrating AWS SQS with my NestJS application, but I'm experiencing significantly slow message processing. I've tried multiple approaches, including custom integration and using packages like ssut/nestjs-sqs, and I've tested everything locally with LocalStack.
Here are some details about my setup:
Framework: NestJS
SQS Library: ssut/nestjs-sqs
Environment: LocalStack for local testing
Queue Type: FIFO (although switching to standard queues didn't improve performance)
Despite following the documentation and trying different configurations, the message processing seems to be unusually slow. I've also ensured that the message visibility timeout and other queue settings are correctly configured.
Here are some specific questions I have:
Are there any common pitfalls or configuration issues that could lead to slow processing with SQS in a NestJS context?
Has anyone successfully integrated SQS with NestJS and experienced good performance? If so, could you share your setup or any best practices?
Are there any performance tuning recommendations for using SQS with NestJS?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Custom Integration: I implemented a custom service to handle SQS message processing. I expected this to give me more control over the flow and performance, but the processing speed remained slow.
Using ssut/nestjs-sqs Package: I switched to the ssut/nestjs-sqs package, following the official documentation closely. I expected this to simplify the integration and improve performance, but I’m still seeing slow message processing.
Testing with LocalStack: I used LocalStack to simulate the AWS environment for testing. I expected similar performance to what I would see in production, but I noticed that processing times were still not optimal.
FIFO Queue Configuration: I set up my SQS queue as a FIFO queue to ensure message order and deduplication. I expected this to enhance reliability, but it did not resolve the speed issues.
Visibility Timeout and Other Settings: I adjusted the visibility timeout and other queue settings to optimize processing. However, these changes did not lead to improved performance.
